# Remove a substring of filename

Tags: filenames

I have a filename that will vary up to the suffix `.csv.new`. I need to extract the stem.  Example `file1_test.csv.new`.  I need to strip out the stem `file1_test` to create a variable `file1_test.err`.

Comment: So...  you haven't tried anything? Because you only know pl/sql? That's not how this works. That's now how *any* of this works. You should start by searching Google for "remove substring in unix". You should have started there before asking this question, honestly, but you should definitely go do that now.

Comment: It's help to know your shell (bash, ksh, zsh, etc) and your operating system-- to focus the answers appropriately.

Comment: Hang on, do you really want shell variables with variable names? Or do you want to store the name (e.g. `file1_test.err`) in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Run this. The `%` makes bash delete the globbing match backwards.

```
for F in *.csv.new; do
  touch ${F%.csv.new}.err
done
```

If you have the files

```
file1_test.csv.new
file2_test.csv.new
```

you will get

```
file1_test.err
file2_test.err
```

Comment: The `*` in `${F%*.csv.new}` was superfluous: `%` deletes the shortest matching substring, and the shortest match for the `*` wildcard is the empty string. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`basename` is a lightweight tool to do what you asked for, e.g.

```
$ basename file1_test.csv.new .csv.new
file1_test
```

and thus

```
var=$(basename file1_test.csv.new).err
```

where `var` will contain `file1_test.err` as desired.